# resize image to specific height and width value using im4java?

Tags: imagemagick, jmagick, im4java

I need to re-size image to any specific height and width value. But I'm not getting resized result. here is my code, please tell me either i'm doing something wrong or missing something.

```
IMOperation operationSmall = new IMOperation();
        operationSmall.addImage("conf/error.png");
        operationSmall.resize(300, 1000); // w*h
        operationSmall.addImage("conf/errir_small.png");
```

Original Image size:  1280x960 px.
re-sized image size:  300x225

I tried to give different values, I'm only having issues in height. 
their doc is not complete and no code example I find on internet except that using `scale (it skip filtering)` may solve this problem. but how to use scale in code I have not idea.

Comment: I don't read or understand java much, but at the commandline you need an exclamation mark to disregard aspect ratio and force exact dimensions, like this `convert -resize 300x200! image...`. In the Java docs, there seems to be an option of adding a special 3rd parameter, so I guess you may need `operationSmall.resize(300,300,'!')` or something similar... or maybe Java uses double quotes for strings rather than the single quotes I suggested.

Comment: thank you it worked. 

if you add your comment in answer,  I can +1 for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't read or understand java much, but at the command-line you need an exclamation mark to force ImageMagick to disregard aspect ratio and resize to exact/specific dimensions, like this:

```
convert -resize 300x200! image....
```

In the Java docs, there seems to be an option of adding a special 3rd parameter, so I guess you may need

```
operationSmall.resize(300,1000,'!');
```

or something similar... or maybe Java uses double quotes rather than the single quotes I suggested.